# how is the code in amp-html to have a multi column image responsive?

Tags: html, css, amp-html, responsive-images

This is what I meant, from this  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_images_side_by_side2) with the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
}

/* Create three equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    flex: 33.33%;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Images Side by Side</h2>
<p>How to create side-by-side images with CSS Flexbox:</p>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_snow.jpg" alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

With that code, there is one row with three images side by side and if the screen is resized those 3 images gets bigger/smaller accordingly proportionally.

I've found from the internet about amp-html something like this :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AMP #0</title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="amps.html" >
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
  <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>

  <style amp-custom>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:auto;
  }

  </style>

  <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
   <amp-img class="child-flex-default" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pSECrJ82R7-AqeBCOEPGPM9iG9OEIQ_QXcbubWIOdkY=w400-h300-no-n" layout=flex-item></amp-img>
  <amp-img class="child-flex-default" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5rcQ32ml8E5ONp9f9-Rf78IofLb9QjS5_0mqsY1zEFc=w400-h300-no-n" layout=flex-item></amp-img>
  <amp-img class="child-flex-default" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Z4gtm5Bkxyv21Z2PtbTf95Clb9AE4VTR6olbBKYrenM=w400-h300-no-n" layout=flex-item></amp-img>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But the one in the amp-html code doesn't make those three images grow/shrink when I resize the screen.

So I tried to change the style like this :

```
  <style amp-custom>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 200px;
    margin:auto;
  }

  </style>
```

The width of those three images did grow/shrink when I resize the screen, but not the height. So I tried to change the `height: 200px;` into `max-height: 200px;` then all the three images gone (no display). The same result if I deleted the height attribute in that style, no display.

My question :
*How do I write the code in order that the width and the height goes proportionally when I resize the screen ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your style as follows:

```
 .container {
    display: flex;
 }

 .child-flex-default{
    width: 100%; // Or 33.33%, or whatever. Just make sure you specify in %
 }
```

Now, you have to change your `amp-img` tags as follows with `layout="responsive"` :

```
<amp-img width="150" height="200" layout="responsive" class="child-flex-default" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/pSECrJ82R7-AqeBCOEPGPM9iG9OEIQ_QXcbubWIOdkY=w400-h300-no-n"></amp-img>
<amp-img width="150" height="200" layout="responsive" class="child-flex-default" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/5rcQ32ml8E5ONp9f9-Rf78IofLb9QjS5_0mqsY1zEFc=w400-h300-no-n"></amp-img>
<amp-img width="150" height="200" layout="responsive" class="child-flex-default" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/Z4gtm5Bkxyv21Z2PtbTf95Clb9AE4VTR6olbBKYrenM=w400-h300-no-n"></amp-img>
```

Just note that when you use repsonsive layout you have to specify `width` and `height` attributes. And now your images will resize responsively maintaining the `width`, `height` ratio that you specified.

Comment: Wow... it works ! Thank you very much, Chris Aby Antony. Thank you also for your note about the width and height.